# How to fill a multicolumn listbox

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I know how to create the listbox but I am having some problems to fill a multicolumn listbox. How can i do it?

Comment: Have you tried the `ListView` control?

Comment: You should list the problems you're having so we can more readily help you.

Comment: Where is your data that you plan on using to fill coming from? Database, XML, user input, etc?

Comment: I'm doing it in WinForms.
I don't know how to fill two columns, i only know how to fill the default.
I want to create in each line two columns, and in each column a random number between 1 and the value that is in a textbox.
Can not have two numbers with the same value in all the lines or columns.
An example:
Number in text box: 6
------ Column 1 | Column 2
Line 1    4     |   3
Line 2    2     |   1
Line 3    5     |   6

Comment: Please Edit your question to clean it up.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# MultiColumn Listbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8477212/c-sharp-multicolumn-listbox)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What kind of list control do you use? My first-hand choice for a multicolumn list is typically the ListView, that you can populate like so:

```
foreach (var item in someDataList)
{
    // create the list view item (which makes the first column)
    ListViewItem lvi = myListView.Items.Add(item.Text);
    // add additional columns
    lvi.SubItems.Add(item.SomeOtherValue);
}
```

Then you set the `View` property to `Details` and edit the `Columns` collection and needed. and you should be good to go.