# C# MultiColumn Listbox

Tags: c#, winforms, list, listbox

I have two the following code

```
    List<string> _items = new List<string>();
    List<string> _items2 = new List<string>();
```

I want to add both of them into a single multi-column Listbox

Column1 could be _items whereas Column2 can be _items2

I don't know how to add items2 to a 2nd column

I've added _items to the Listbox by

```
Listbox1.DataSource = _items
```

Thank you

Comment: is there any problem with using Listview because it has more flexibility over listbox

Comment: I don't think you can have two columns in a list box.  I think you'll need either a listView or a dataGridView

Comment: It would probably be easier to use two ListBoxes since it looks like there is nothing in common between these two lists.

Comment: There is a property for ListBox that is called "Multicolumn"

Comment: @CocoaDev you can refer msdn document for multilistbox column but i strongly recommend using listview

Comment: Here is what im trying to do. I want to have 2 ListView (Listbox). One LV (or LB) will have data from 1 file. The other will have 2 columns. Eventually I want to compare the 2 and change the background for the LV rows that match.

Answer (score 2):

The above answer did not work for me, using .NetCF, this slight variation did:

```
myListView.Columns.Add("Nr"); //column 1 heading
myListView.Columns.Add("Desc"); //column 2 heading
myListView.View = View.Details; //make column headings visible
foreach (var item in someDataList) //item has strings for each column of one row
{
    // create new ListViewItem
    ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(item.Text1);
    lvi.SubItems.Add(item.Text2);
    // add the listviewitem to a new row of the ListView control
    myListView.Items.Add(lvi); //show Text1 in column1, Text2 in col2
}
```

Comment: The OP is using a ListBox control, not a ListView.