# ListBox & Two dimensional array VB.net

Tags: vb.net, multidimensional-array, listbox

Im new to VB, and I'm trying to fill a listbox from a two dimensional array but i have no clue where to start with this. Can someone help me out and point me in the right direction

Regards,

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8477212/c-sharp-multicolumn-listbox for a language-agnostic answer.

Comment: You are going to have to give us an example of the array and what you would like to see in the list box for that content.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
listBox1.MultiColumn = true;
    listBox1.DataSource = cars;
```